# Missing file reference in filelist of linked file in custom extension

Tags: typo3-9.x

We use TYPO3 V9.5.45 with PHP7.3.33. There is an own made custom extension with backend layout. One field is called "remark" and is defined of type = text in the database table. In the related tca configuration is following code:

```
'remark' => array(  
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'text',
        'cols' => 40,
        'rows' => 15,
        'enableRichtext' => true,
    ),
),
```

On the backend if you write text in this field and set a link to a for example pdf-file, the link works as expected. However, the reference to this file is not included in the file list.

Am I missing something in connection with sys_file_reference in the custom extension?
I am grateful for any help or advice.